# Tangent space of $U(n+1)/U(1)\times U(n)$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry

Let $U(n)=\{X\in gl(n,\mathbb{C})|XX^*=I_n\},$ where $gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices whose entries are complex numbers, $X^*=\bar{X}^T$ and $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

I want to compute the tangent space $T_0\left(U(n+1)/U(1)\times U(n)\right),$ where $0=[I_n]$ is the coset of $I_n$ in $U(n+1)/U(1)\times U(n).$ I don't know how to compute it. But I know the result is $$T_0\left(U(n+1)/U(1)\times U(n)\right)=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\-a^*&0\end{pmatrix}\right|a\in\mathbb{C}^n\right\}$$

Comment: Have you thought about taking an obvious path through $0$ and differentiating?

Comment: May you give me a hint about the path you said? I don't know how to construct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural interpretation of $T_0(U(n+1)/(U(1)\times U(n))$ is as the quotient $\mathfrak u(n+1)/(\mathfrak u(1)\times\mathfrak u(n))$ of the Lie algebras. This comes from the fact that the projection $p:U(n+1)\to U(n)/(U(1)\times U(n))$ is a submersion, so its derivative at $I_n$ defines a surjection $\mathfrak u(n+1)\to T_0(U(n+1)/(U(1)\times U(n))$ and the kernel is clearly the indicated Lie subalgebra. Now you could take any linear subspace in $\mathfrak u(n+1)$ and restrict the derivative to this subspace to obtain an identification with $T_0(U(n+1)/(U(1)\times U(n))$.

The space you indicate in the question is such a complement and it is a particularly natural choice, since it is invariant under the action of the subgroup $U(1)\times U(n)$ (coming from the restriction of the adjoint action of $U(n+1)$. This also has the advantage that the canonical action of $U(1)\times U(n)$ on the quotient $\mathfrak u(n+1)/(\mathfrak u(1)\times\mathfrak u(n))$ is isomrphic to the action on that specific.

Comment: I don't know how to compute $ker(p_*)$. Here is my try.

For any $X\in ker(p_*)$, we know that $p_*(X)=0.$ On the other hand, we can choose a path $c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to U(n+1)$ such that $c(0)=I_{n+1},c'(0)=X,$ then
$$p_*(X)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0 (p\circ c)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0 ([c(t)])$$
I don't know how to continue.

Comment: It is not really necessary to compute a lot here. If you have a curve $c$ that has values in the subgroup $U(1)\times U(n)$ then evidently $p\circ c(t)=0$ for any $t$, so $c'(0)\in ker(p_*)$. This shows that $\mathfrak u(1)\times\mathfrak u(n)$ is contained in the kernel and looking at dimensions it has to equal the kernel.